# Put a bar as background of bars in histogram plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a histogram plot and different bars has different color. I want to show a background (the same width as the bar width) and also change the bar from rectangular to oval. I attached an that show the way I want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
rating = [9, 5, 7, 6]
objects = ('h', 'b', 'c', 'a')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('cool')
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(rating), vmax=max(rating))
plt.barh(y_pos, rating, align='center', color=cmap(norm(np.array(rating))))
plt.show()
```

The maximum length of the bars is 10. In the following image, we can see a bar with two colors (blue and black background). Can you please help me with that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FancyBboxPatch` and `seaborn`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.patches import FancyBboxPatch


mydict = {
    'Index': ['3', '2', '1', '0'],
    'rating': [9, 5, 7, 6],
    'max_rating': [10, 10, 10, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict).set_index('Index')
cmap = plt.get_cmap('cool')
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(df.rating), vmax=max(df.rating))




plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 2))
ax = sns.barplot(x=df.max_rating, y=df.index, color='black')
ax2 = sns.barplot(x=df.rating, y=df.index, palette="pastel")
ax2.set_xlim(-1, 11)

new_patches_1 = []
new_patches_2 = []
for idx in range(len(df.index)-1, -1, -1):
    patch_1 = ax.patches[idx]
    bb_1 = patch_1.get_bbox()
    color = patch_1.get_facecolor()
    p_bbox_1 = FancyBboxPatch((bb_1.xmin, bb_1.ymin),
                            abs(bb_1.width), abs(bb_1.height),
                            boxstyle="round,pad=0.08,rounding_size=0.8",
                            ec="none", fc=color,
                            mutation_aspect=0.5
                            )
    patch_1.remove()
    new_patches_1.append(p_bbox_1)
    
    patch_2 = ax2.patches[idx]
    bb_2 = patch_2.get_bbox()
    color = patch_2.get_facecolor()
    p_bbox_2 = FancyBboxPatch((bb_2.xmin, bb_2.ymin),
                            df.rating[idx], abs(bb_2.height),
                            boxstyle="round,pad=0.08,rounding_size=0.8",
                            ec="none", fc=color,
                            mutation_aspect=0.5
                            
                            )
    patch_2.remove()
    new_patches_2.append(p_bbox_2)

for patch_1 in new_patches_1:
    ax.add_patch(patch_1)
    
for patch_2 in new_patches_2:
    ax2.add_patch(patch_2)

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

Then you get the figure:

[image]

**Update :**

Since you want to change the space between each bar, I add a variable to adjust the `height` :

The code in the first loop change to :

```
new_patches_1 = []
new_patches_2 = []
height = 0.6
for idx in range(len(df.index)-1, -1, -1):
    patch_1 = ax.patches[idx]
    bb_1 = patch_1.get_bbox()
    color = patch_1.get_facecolor()
    p_bbox_1 = FancyBboxPatch((bb_1.xmin, bb_1.ymin),
                            abs(bb_1.width), height,
                            boxstyle="round,pad=0.08,rounding_size=0.8",
                            ec="none", fc=color,
                            mutation_aspect=height*0.625
                            )
    patch_1.remove()
    new_patches_1.append(p_bbox_1)
    
    patch_2 = ax2.patches[idx]
    bb_2 = patch_2.get_bbox()
    color = patch_2.get_facecolor()
    p_bbox_2 = FancyBboxPatch((bb_2.xmin, bb_2.ymin),
                            df.rating[idx], height,
                            boxstyle="round,pad=0.08,rounding_size=0.8",
                            ec="none", fc=color,
                            mutation_aspect=height*0.625
                            
                            )
    patch_2.remove()
    new_patches_2.append(p_bbox_2)
```

You can change the variable `height`, to adjust the distance.

**Attention: the `height` should bigger than 0.**

**Update 2:**

If you need custom color, I add a variable `color`, just after the definition of the variable `norm`

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('cool')
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(df.rating), vmax=max(df.rating))
color = cmap(norm(df.rating))
```

Then change the plot of the `ax2` to this :

```
ax2 = sns.barplot(x=df.rating, y=df.index, palette=color)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another question. I want to increase the space between each bar. Do you know how we can set that?

Comment: @ Sadcow I made an update to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another question and I promise that this is my last one:) Here we use the pallet for coloring. And set the colors for each bar differently. However, I want to change the color of each bar based on its value, Do you have any thoughts on how to set that? I know that I should use the norm, but with my tries, it does not work.

Comment: @ Sadcow I made another update to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. However, it does not work. If I put 4 for two ratings, the colors of the two bars are different. I have 10 indexes in my actual data and I want (for example) the color of the index of rating>9 to be close to each other. Thank you for your help. You help me a lot with this question.